# React Material UI: How to use material-ui platinum themes?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use one of the platinum themes from React Material-UI, link below:

https://material-ui.com/premium-themes/

but I can't find instructions for how to use them in my application. Can someone explain how can I use a platinum theme in my React application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use one of the free premium themes, just click the link to go to the "Source Code" and then you can look at the code for the example. For instance, for the Paperbase theme you can find the source code for the theme here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/premium-themes/paperbase/Paperbase.js.

Just copy the parts you want to leverage into your own project and then you can modify it as desired.